# Inconsistent linebreaks in similar situations

Tags: line-breaking, exam

Below is a part of my output file

[image]

The inconsistency is there at the end of the second line of each question. The word *diameters* is intact and broken in the first and the second question respectively. Whereas the codes of those two parts are exactly the same. Here is the part of the code.

**Edit:** Full code follows here.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{exam}
\usepackage[left=0.25in,right=0.75in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,footskip=.15in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, amsfonts}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{lastpage,refcount}
\footer{}{\small\thepage}{\ifodd\value{page}\relax
    \if\thepage\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}\relax
    \else \tiny {\mbox{\kern\dimexpr+4.75in\relax}}\boxed{\textbf{Turn Over}}
    \fi
    \fi}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\setlength\@rightmargin{0.5in}
\patchcmd\setup@point@toks{\llap{\padded@point@block}}{\rlap{\padded@point@block}}{}{}
\patchcmd\droppoints{\llap{\padded@point@block}}{\rlap{\padded@point@block}}{}{}
\patchcmd\droptotalpoints{\llap{\total@block}}{\rlap{\total@block}}{}{}
\patchcmd\droptotalbonuspoints{\llap{\bonustotal@block}}{\rlap{\bonustotal@block}}{}{}
\makeatother


\marksnotpoints
\bracketedpoints
\pointsdroppedatright


\renewcommand\partlabel{(\textbf{\alph{partno}})}
\renewcommand{\thesubpart}{(\textit{\roman{subpart}})}
\renewcommand{\subpartlabel}{\thesubpart}
\renewcommand\questionlabel{\textbf{\thequestion.}}


\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\renewcommand{\a}{\alpha}
\renewcommand{\b}{\beta}
\newcommand{\g}{\gamma}
\renewcommand{\d}{\delta}
\newcommand{\e}{\epsilon}

\begin{document}


%
%
%
\begin{questions}
%
%Qn 1. [4X3]
%
    \question[4$\times$3]
        Answer any \textsc{Three}.\droppoints\vspace{2ex}
        \begin{parts}
%1.a. [4]
            \part
                If exists, give an example of\vspace{1ex}
                \begin{subparts}
%1.a. (i) [2]
                    \subpart[2]
                        a metric space which has a descending sequence $ \{F_n\} $ of non-empty closed sets (i.e., $ F_{n+1}\subseteq F_{n} $) with vanishing diameters, i.e., $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\d(F_n)=0 $; but $ \bigcap\limits_{n\in\N}F_n=\emptyset $.\droppoints\vspace{1ex}
%1.a. (ii) [2]
                    \subpart[2]
                        a metric space which has a descending sequence $ \{F_n\} $ of non-empty closed sets (i.e., $ F_{n+1}\subseteq F_{n} $) with vanishing diameters, i.e., $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\d(F_n)=0 $; but $ \bigcap\limits_{n\in\N}F_n $ contains more than one element. \droppoints
                \end{subparts}\vspace{2ex}
%1.b. [4]
        \end{parts}\vspace{4ex}

\end{questions}
\begin{center}
    \vspace{10ex}\rule{6cm}{0.4pt}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Any idea why does this happen and how to avoid this? I am doing this in `exam` document clas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: TeX realizes that it cannot fit “element” in the third line, so it has to adjust the interword spaces and does so *globally* in the paragraph, in order to avoid visually incompatible lines (one stretched and one tight, for instance) next to each other. Such spacing adjustment may involve adding hyphenation points in order to minimize global badness of the paragraph.

Comment: Please make the code snippet into a full featured document that reproduces the output. Well, I can but only disallowing hyphenation of “element”.

Comment: line breaking is an optimisation over the entire paragraph so any change anywhere in a paragraph can change all the breaks for the whole paragraph so the differences that you show are expected as the texts are different. Unrelated but as your image shows forcing `\limits` in inline math destroys the linespacing of the paragraph, it should normally be avoided.

Comment: Ok. I understood your points. But still, for an amateur in LaTex like me, it seems a little inconsistent. Yes, I tried the cases where the first question is copied replacing the second one and secondly, keeping the `limit` in display math. Both cases, it worked. But if I want to keep things in inline mode, is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: The whole point of inline math layout is to use a compressed format so that the math fits in the standard linespacing of the paragraph, using inline math then using `\limits` to force the subscript underneath just breaks that completely, it is better to use the inline form, or set the formula as a display using `\[..\]` not `$..$`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeX realizes that it cannot fit “element” in the third line, so it has to adjust the interword spaces and does so *globally* in the paragraph, in order to avoid visually incompatible lines (one stretched and one tight, for instance) next to each other. Such spacing adjustment may involve adding hyphenation points in order to minimize global badness of the paragraph.

If you look at the second paragraph, you'll see well that no hyphenation in ‘diameters’ would lead to a very stretched out third line.

If you add `\usepackage{microtype}`, then a decent break point can be found with the same first two lines.

Don't expect this to be a *panacea*, though.

[image]